# web scraping For loop stuck on first item on list- python

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to loop through a list of names, it seems it should be very simple but it's not working. Only receiving the first name on the list and nothing more! why is it not moving on to the NEXT name!?

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('http://www.aus.edu/info/200170/college_of_architecture_art_and_design/269/department_of_architecture/4')
soup = BeautifulSoup (page.content, "html.parser")

content = soup.find(class_="supContact")
content_items = content.find_all(class_="contactToggle selected")
names = content_items[0]

s_name = []
for item in name: 
    s_name.append(content.find(class_="contactToggle selected").text)
    if not names:
        continue
print(s_name)

#print(names.prettify())
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not mixing up `name` with `names` in the for loop and `if/continue`?

Comment: according to your filter `class_="contactToggle selected"` it'll return one name at all, i.e. `content_items` contains only one item. So it's unclear what exactly you want to achieve, voting to close this question

Comment: no worries, I've fixed the issue. thanks